# How to write a list to update a text document, when using classes and sort?

Tags: python, list, class, text, append

I have the following data over players in a text doc named `file.txt`, in the format: 
 `Name`, `Time ratio`, `Matches Won`, `Matches Played`, `Win Ratio`

```
Andrew, 0.72, 5, 10, 0.5
Brett, 0.82, 8, 10, 0.8
Carl, 0.92, 12, 15, 0.8
... (and so on.)
```

**Task:** I need to be able to choose two players for a match and then choose the winner. So when I run the program the nr of played matches goes up on for both players, the nr of wins goes up one for the winner, and the win ratio to update. So that I later can update and print the leaderboard ranked by win ratio.

**Problem:** I get the program to play a game and add the correct numbers and sort the leaderboard but I can't figure out how to update my text doc.

My class file: `gamestat.py`

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name, tratio, won, played):
        self.name = name
        self.tratio = tratio
        self.won = won
        self.played = played

        self.winquota = round(won/played, 3)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.tratio} {self.won} {self.played} {self.winquota}"

    def __lt__(self, other):  #
        return self.winquota < other.winquota

    def winningplayer(self):
        self.won = self.won + 1

    def nrplayed(self):
        self.played = self.played + 1 `
```

Program file (main)

```
from tstats import Spelare

def filereader(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        y = []
        for row in f:
            playerdata = rad.split(',')
            player = Spelare(playerdata[0], float(playerdata[1]), int(playerdata[2]),
                             int(playerdata[3]))
            y.append(player)

    return y

def main():
    y=filereader('file.txt')
    y.sort(reverse=True)
    for individual in y:
        print(individual)
    n1 = int(input("Välj spelare 1"))
    n2 = int(input("Vlj spelare 2"))

    name1 = int(n1 - 1)  #bc 0 index
    name2 = int(n2-1)
    y[name1].nrplayed()
    y[name2].nrplayed()

    winner = int(input("Name winner"))
    if winner == name1:
        y[name1].winningplayer()
    elif winner == name2:
        y[name2].winningplayer()

    y.sort(reverse=True)
    for individual in y:
        print(individual)


main()
```

So I get the right data but I have done something now which makes it behave weirdly, so something is out of place, but the main question I have is how I can put my new data created in the list y in file.txt.

**What is a good technique/method to go about doing that?** I've tried looking it up but couldn't find a solution for when the text is in a csv format.

If you have any suggestions/links to similar answered threads/answers please leave it down below.

Comment: Python's standard library has a module called "csv" for exactly that.

Comment: As mentioned by @MichaelButscher, the "csv" module is recommended when dealing with csv type files. You may not have any issues with commas in names for example but if you did, just writing to text could cause you to have mismatched numbers of columns per row. You can avoid that by using dedicated modules like "csv"

Comment: You will likely need to rewrite the whole file to update it. As others have mentioned, Python has a built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module that can read and write (text) files in the format you're using.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this as you have a well written class would be:

```py
def save(list_data, output='file_updated.txt'):
    with open(output, "w") as file:
        for player in list_data:
            file.write(str(player))
    print(f"Data saved in : {output}")
```

For the above function to be clean, you should add `\n` at the end of your `__str__` method.

```py
  def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.tratio} {self.won} {self.played} {self.winquota}\n"
```